# Tool to make long documents in HTML and PDF formats

Tags: documentation-generator

I'm about to start writing a large (e.g. 30k words) "handbook" type document for all our products.  I'd like to be able to offer this as a HTML document, split into chapters and sections, with each section on it's own page and good navigation, and also as a PDF download with clear structure and internal links.

Some examples of the type of HTML output I'm looking for:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#autodoc
- https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Surface_Extrudes.htm

Some software I've found so far:

- LaTeX: I don't know exactly how, but I'm sure it's possible. Feel free to suggest packages.
- Sphinx and MkDocs: These seem like the best fit so far, but are more aimed at building docs from commented code. I don't need that - I'll be writing the docs directly.
- MS Word: rather clunky for long docs, and I doubt I can get the HTML features I want. Perhaps extensions or third party tools which can read the word docs?

Features I want:

- Easy to write, maintain and update the source files. Markdown, reStructuredText etc are fine.
- Easy to set up and build (in case a less-technical colleague needs to do it)
- Project/tool seems likeley to be supported well into the future
- PDF output with automatic section labels, table of contents, internal links
- HTML output with navigation sidebar, preferably with fold-out sections and subsections
- HTML themes, including responsive ones, which can be modified with our branding
- HTML output broken into section-sized pages, with the ability to link to those pages subsections/paragraphs within.
- Simple easy way to include graphics (png / jpeg / svg etc)
- Simple easy way to include tables.

Nice to haves:

- Single (long) page HTML output option
- ePub and similar format output for devices that support those formats
- Free / open source preferred

Comment: Have a look at pandoc - reads markdown and produces html and pdf

Comment: visual code with live server?